# Sumar en total MYSQL

Tags: mysql

tengo estas dos tablas:

```
                REPORTEBETEITIVA
_______________________________________________________
|  idReporteBeteitiva   |    HorasTrabajo |Trabajador |  
-------------------------------------------------------
|        1              |         8       |     1     |
-------------------------------------------------------
|        2              |         8       |     1     |
-------------------------------------------------------
|        3              |        14       |     2     |
-------------------------------------------------------


                        TRABAJADOR
    ________________________________________
    |  idTrabajador   |  Nombre  |  Cedula |  
    ----------------------------------------
    |        1        |   PEDRO  | 1054632 |
    ----------------------------------------
    |        2        |   CAMILO | 1234555 |
    ----------------------------------------
```

Quiero que se sume el total de horas trabajadas, pero ya tengo esta consulta que me agrupa las horas por la "Cedula" :

```
SELECT trabajador.Nombre, sum(HorasTrabajo) as HorasT FROM 
reportebeteitiva INNER JOIN trabajador ON reportebeteitiva.Trabajador = 
trabajador.idTrabajador group by trabajador.Cedula;
```

entonces solo me falta la parte de TOTAL = 28.

Asi quedaria:

```
       ______________________
       |  Nombre |  HorasT  |   
       ----------------------
       |   Pedro |   16     |
       ----------------------
       |  Camilo |   12     | 
-----------------------------
|TOTAL           |   28     |
-----------------------------
```

Gracias por la ayuda :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que agregar la clausula `WITH ROLLUP` asi:

```
SELECT trabajador.Nombre, sum(HorasTrabajo) as HorasT FROM 
reportebeteitiva INNER JOIN trabajador ON reportebeteitiva.Trabajador = 
trabajador.idTrabajador 
group by trabajador.Cedula WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Amigo eso no lo puedo almacenar en una variable???   Y quitar que me salga la celda de nombre osea TOTAL en blanco sin ningun nombre

Comment: @CristianLRS1997 muestra el resultado de aplicar el with rollup por que así a mi en un ejemplo similar me otorga lo que busco

Comment: Si se puede guardar en una variable, eso depende de que lenguaje estes usando y de como despliegues tu tabla

Comment: Es para mandar la consulta hecha a php para hacer un reporte en fpdf

Comment: Si estas usando php, el resultado de rollup es el ultimo row de la consulta, y lo manipulas como cualquier otro row